# Character arrays declared sequentially overlapping

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

I am trying to declare two character arrays, one after each other. When I do this the arrays seem to overlap onto each other.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    char cmnd[2] = {'l', 's'};
    char flags[1] = {'a'};
    std::cout << "cmnd array: " << cmnd << std::endl;
    std::cout << "flags array: " << flags << std::endl;
}
```

The output of this code then becomes:

```
cmnd array: ls
flags array: als
```

According to the output my flags array which should only contain `{'a'}` actually contains `{'a','l','s'}`.
Why does this occur? Thanks in advance for any insight on this issue.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your cmnd and flags arrays, in and of themselves. cmnd really is an array with 2 characters, and flags really is an array with 1 character. What is "wrong" is your expectation about what the line "std::cout << "flags array: " << flags << std::endl;" should do. This line will print characters starting from the address of flags, until a null character is encountered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++ all plain `char` strings are really called ***null-terminated*** byte strings.

This null-terminator is what tells all functions handling such strings where the string ends. If a string lacks a null-terminator they will go out of bounds, and you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you want to have an array of characters used as strings, you need to make sure they contain a null-terminator. In your case it's very simple: Don't specify a size for the array and use literal strings when initializing:

```
char cmnd[] = "ls";
char flags[] = "a";
```

Now `cmnd` will be an array of *three* characters, and initialized to contain `'l'`, `'s'` and the null-terminator `'\0'`. Similarly `flags` will be an array of two characters, initialized to `'a'` and `'\0'`.

Answer (score 2):

`std::cout` treats the character arrays as strings, but neither of yours are NULL-terminated but `cout` continues on until it finds a NULL character. It looks like your `flags` array immediately precedes the `cmnd` array in memory, and a 0 occurs in the memory location immediately following the `cmnd` array.

If you want to treat them as strings to `std::cout`, add a null character, that is a '\0' or just 0, to the end of each array. If not, change how you pass them to `cout`.

Comment: It should be `0` (or `'\0'` equivalently), not `NULL`. The latter may be `nullptr` which will not work as a `char`. `NULL` is only supposed to be used as null pointer constant and even then it is succeeded by `nullptr` since C++11.

Comment: @walnut You're right, I should not have used NULL there, where I was referring the null ('\0') character.